# Dataset Example Non Parametric Statistics

Tags: statistics, dataset

I need to find a group of datasets to apply some Non Parametric tests. Anyone knows where can I find example datasets to download them and apply those methods?

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure what you need, try the wine dataset from R package ordinal:

```
library(ordinal)
data(wine)
```

And information about the dataset:

> ```
> The ‘wine’ data set is adopted from Randall(1989) and from a
>  factorial experiment on factors determining the bitterness of
>  wine. Two treatment factors (temperature and contact) each have
>  two levels. Temperature and contact between juice and skins can be
>  controlled when cruching grapes during wine production. Nine
>  judges each assessed wine from two bottles from each of the four
>  treatment conditions, hence there are 72 observations in all.
> ```